# Multi-element selector: attach event efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have seen multiple variations of attaching a `change` event to various types of elements but have yet seen any logical reason to choose one style over another.

In a current project, I am using the `$(..).change(...)` pattern to attach a handler to each of the elements I am selecting. I am noticing that after about 15k-20k captured objects, the handler seems to have a noticeable lag time associated (roughly 400-600 milliseconds).

Is there a more efficient approach to attaching an event to multiple elements, while minimizing the noticeable lag differential?

Thought about extracting the "Evaluation Logic" into a standalone function but was unsure if there would be any real gain.

### Template (handlebars):

```
{{#if rows.length}}
<tbody>
    {{#each rows}}
    <tr id="rowId_{{Id}}">
        <td>{{DateHour}}</td>
        <td>
            <input id="hid_{{Id}}" type="hidden" value="{{Value}}" />
            <input id="txt_{{Id}}" type="text" name="name" value="{{Value}}" />
        </td>
        <td>{{Value2}}</td>
        <td>{{Value3}}</td>
        <td>{{Value4}}</td>
        <td>{{Value5}}</td>
        <td>{{Value6}}</td>
        <td>{{Value7}}</td>
        <td>{{Value8}}</td>
        <td>{{Value9}}</td>
        <td>{{Value10}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
{{/if}}
```

### Current Pattern:

```
$('[id^="txt"]').change(function (evt) {
    // Capture the Source Elements 
    var src = evt.currentTarget

    // Capture all controls with the same [ID] suffix to their ID attribute, then capture the Hidden Element
    //      of that group.  The Hidden Element is the Original Value
    var orig = $('[id$=' + src.id.split('_')[1] + ']').filter('[id^=hid]').val();
    var mod = $(src).val();

    if (mod != orig) {
        // Original Value was modified
        $(src).addClass('modified');
    } else {
        $(src).removeClass('modified');
    }
});
```

### Question:

Is there a better approach?

Comment: The easiest and best is to delegate event to closest common ancestor

Comment: [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/): `$('table').on('change', '[id^="txt"]', function(evt) { ... })`

Comment: Not sure if it's practical, but if there are objects that you *don't* need to listen for change events on, can you exclude them, or maybe `return` right away if they don't apply? Or can you remove the handler from "old" objects that may not need to be monitored anymore?

Comment: @freginold unfortunately, the current implementation could have up to 56k rows within the TableBody, client "need" but definitely not my "want" ;)  I need to handle logic for any change from the "original" value or back to it.  So when I submit the "update" ajax, I only send back the data that has actually changed...hence the `addClass(...)` and `removeClass(...)`

Comment: @Andreas for the moment, I like that implementation a lot better than an event on every single child element that i need to monitor.